# Java: Issues with JOptionPane/storing output into a variable

Tags: java

I am writing a code that extracts the first initial of words and makes it into an acronym.

For example the sentence is `random number gen` the answer is `RNG`.

I have it working but I am trying to show the result in `JOptionPane`. I can't figure how to save the final output (3 initials) to a variable and then show it in the JOptionPane.

Is there a way I could store the `System.out.print` output into a string variable?

I originally tried storing the `System.out.print` into a variable but it gives me an error of void cannot be converted to string.

So i tried storing the letters to the variable 'initials' but it only stores one (which makes sense).
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

```
public class ThreeLetterAcronym {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String answer;
        String upperAnswer;
        int number;
        char letter;
        String initial = "";

        answer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter three words?", "Input", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        upperAnswer = answer.toUpperCase();
        upperAnswer = " " + upperAnswer;
        number = upperAnswer.length();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
            letter = upperAnswer.charAt(i);
            if (letter == ' ') {
                initial = Character.toString(upperAnswer.charAt(i + 1));
                sb.append(initial);
                System.out.print(upperAnswer.charAt(i + 1));
            }
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, sb.toString(), "Acronym", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `initial` in your output message dialog which will reset every time when loop continues and stores the last one. So, I have stored it to `StringBuilder`. Here is the working code,

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ThreeLetterAcronym {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String answer;
        String upperAnswer;
        int number;
        char letter;
        String initial = "";

        answer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter three words?", "Input", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        upperAnswer = answer.toUpperCase();
        upperAnswer = " " + upperAnswer;
        number = upperAnswer.length();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
            letter = upperAnswer.charAt(i);
            if (letter == ' ') {
                initial = Character.toString(upperAnswer.charAt(i + 1));
                sb.append(initial);
                System.out.print(upperAnswer.charAt(i + 1));
            }
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, sb.toString(), "Acronym", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

Comment: I did not think about using StringBuilder. Thank you.